# More than one preparestatement in jsp

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, insert

Can i have more than one preparestatement in one .jsp file? I´m trying to execute this "jsp file", but this code doesnt work for me.
Something like this:

```
<%
    String login = request.getParameter("login");
    String pwd = request.getParameter("password");
    String name = request.getParameter("name");

    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement pstatement = null;
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    int updateQuery = 0;
    if (login != null && password != null && full_name != null && ulevel != null && team_id != null) {
        if (login != "" && password != "" && full_name != "" && ulevel != "" && team_id != "") {
            try {
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/<mydatabase>", "<mylogin>", "<mypwd>");
                String queryString_1 = "INSERT INTO users (login,password) VALUES (?, ?)";
                pstatement = connection.prepareStatement(queryString_1);
                pstatement.setString(1, login);
                pstatement.setString(2, password);
                updateQuery = pstatement.executeUpdate();
                String queryString_2 = "INSERT INTO members (name) VALUES (?)";
                pstatement = connection.prepareStatement(queryString_2);
                pstatement.setString(1, name);
                updateQuery = pstatement.executeUpdate();
                if(updateQuery_1 != 0 && updateQuery_2 != 0) {
                   response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                out.println("Unable to connect to database.");
                } finally {
                pstatement.close();
                connection.close();
            }
        } 
    } 
%>
```

Comment: Yes, you can. Ultimately you must have a `PreparedStatement` per SQL query.

Comment: did you try multiple preparedstatements? If so, what result and/or errors did you receive? What did you expect to get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have as many `PreparedStatement`s  as you need.

To improve your code:
1. You must declare int updateQuery_1 = 0 and updateQuery_2 = 0.
2. You must use `updateQuery_1 = pstatement.executeUpdate();` and `updateQuery_2 = pstatement.executeUpdate();` on your two different sql statements.

Comment: Can you verify the stack-trace of the error from your log or console? Seems there is a connection problem. If you can't resolve it yourself, show it to us.